# Stream event hub using service principal

Tags: python, pyspark, stream, azure-eventhub, azure-service-principal

How do I stream event hub data into a spark dataframe with below details:

1. Service Principal
2. Event hub namespace
3. Event hub name
4. Consumer group

I need to get data into spark dataframe. I do not have event hub connection string.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is as follows

**Step 1** : Generate the connection string using either of the below commands.

- **Getting the connection string with Azure CLI**

  ```
  az eventhubs namespace authorization-rule keys list --resource-group MYRESOURCEGROUP --namespace-name MY
  ```
- **Getting the connection string with Azure PowerShell**

  ```
  Get-AzEventHubKey -ResourceGroupName MYRESOURCEGROUP -NamespaceName MYEHUBNAMESPACE -Aut
  ```

**Step 2 :** Then, For reading the data you can follow either of the examples [Example1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/structured-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md#reading-data-from-event-hubs) ,[Example2](https://lenadroid.github.io/posts/connecting-spark-and-eventhubs.html).

**REFERENCES:**

[Event Hubs get Connection String · MicrosoftDocs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string.md#:%7E:text=%20Get%20connection%20string%20from%20the%20portal%20,Connection%20string-primary%20key%20field.%0A%3A%3A%3Aimage%20type%3D%22content%22%20source%3D%22.%20More%20)